# Open the m file for System Objects in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am trying to use the Communications Toolbox in Matlab. In this toolbox there are a number of built in Systems Objects for example

1) `comm.PSKModulator`

I want to examine the .m file and see how these system objects are implemented. So I wrote down the command

```
open comm.PSMModulator
```

However, that doesnt help. Does anyone know why it doesn't work or maybe one cant access such code?

**Update**

When I write down `which comm.PSKModulator` I receive the following

```
/Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/toolbox/comm/comm/+comm/PSKModulator.p  % comm.PSKModulator constructor
```

and where I write open `comm.PSKModulator` I get

```
Error using open (line 146)
File associated with
'/Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/toolbox/comm/comm/+comm/PSKModulator.p' not found.
```

Thanks

Comment: What happened when you did `open comm.LTEMIMOChannel`? It could be a builtin, in which case you'd just see stub code, or nothing. What does `which comm.LTEMIMOChannel` give you?

Comment: open comm.LTEMIMOChannrl gives me an error.. if i write down comm.LTEMIMOCHANNEL I get the properties of the function that i can change.@andrew janke

Comment: Okay. What's the exact text of that error you got? It's very helpful to include exact descriptions and output in questions like this. And for the other one, not just `comm.LTEMIMOCHANNEL`, but `which comm.LTEMIMOCHANNEL`. `which` is a function that will tell you what a function call expression resolves to, and helps you figure out where and what a function is; for example, if it's a regular function, builtin, Java method, or something else.

Comment: @AndrewJanke thanks for taking the time to explain to me, I have updated the question with what you asked me about. Please let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some System objects may be implemented in C++ and does not have much to show in MATLAB code which might be the reason this is p-coded. You need to check the corresponding Simulink block documentation for description of the algorithm used. You can find documentation for M-PSK Modulator Baseband at http://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/mpskmodulatorbaseband.html which has more description about the algorithm implemented.

Comment: Thanks, I understand why now, what does p-coded mean?

Comment: p-coding is the process which creates a p-file from a .m file. It obfuscates the .m file.

Comment: so basically one cannot access a p-file, right? @Navan